# How can I control the SpeedRatio of a Storyboard inside a VisualState?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, animation, visualstatemanager

Given a Storyboard started by the VisualStateManager as part of a ControlTemplate, how would I adjust the SpeedRatio of that animation based on property changes of the control?

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
          <Storyboard Name="SpinningThing"
                      SpeedRatio="{Binding SpinningSpeedRatio}">
            ...
```

This needs to work in both WPF and Silverlight.

I don't think I can set a binding there for a number of reasons.  Foremost, Storyboard is Freezable so you can't just go setting the SpeedRatio all willy-nilly in WPF.  But, if it's started by the VisualStateManager, can I call SetSpeedRatio on it?

Also, since its parent is a VisualState, doesn't that mean there would be no governing FrameworkElement to relate to for it?

So, if I can't do it with a binding, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it looks like there really is no way to handle this strictly with a binding.  So to account for it, I have hooked events in the code-behind to start/adjust the animations as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving here looking for a UWP solution, you *can* use an `{x:Bind}` on the `SpeedRatio` property of a `Storyboard` and it does dynamically change the speed ratio as you would expect.

```
<Storyboard SpeedRatio="{x:Bind ViewModel.SpinningSpeedRatio, Mode=OneWay}">
```

**Edit**: One caveat is you need to ensure you set the ratio on the `UIThread`, otherwise it will be ignored by the `VisualStateManager`.
The `Storyboard` will still play, but not at the speed you have set.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a {TemplateBinding...} rather than a {Binding...}, but that only works for simple, compatible, types.

You should also be able to bind to the templated control using a ["relative binding source"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent.aspx). This also allows you to use a value convertor if the types do not match.

```
SpeedRation={Binding SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}"
```

I have not tested this in WPF, but Silverlight is normally the feature-restricted one.

Comment: Unfortunately, WPF is where the simple answer falls apart.  In WPF, timelines are Freezable objects, so a binding will not change the actual value of the SpeedRatio.  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.aspx

Also, because it is in a ViewState (I guess), you get the binding error saying "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement for binding...".